# I can't sort a table column by a calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax

Trying to sort a column in my custom date table (a csv file) via a calculated column in the same table but am seeing an error. The calculated column does not reference the column I wish to sort by. Here's the DAX for the calculated column:

```
PeriodOffset =
Dates[Period] + Dates[FiscalYear] * 13
    - CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Dates[Period] ), Dates[Date] = TODAY () )
    - CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Dates[FiscalYear] ), Dates[Date] = TODAY () ) * 13
```

My date table has every date from 2003/4 to 2034/35, along with custom period numbers, calendar and fiscal years etc. The column I am trying to sort is called `PeriodFiscalYear`. Each value in that column has only one entry in the `PeriodOffset` column so it's not that.

The weird thing is, I have had this working in a previous report. In this instance, I was simply trying to recreate the functionality but it won't do it. Even stranger, if I create the `PeriodFiscalYear` column as a calculated column (currently it's hard-coded in the csv file), it works! So I have a sort-of workaround, I would just like to understand what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post 5 rows of sample data so that we could replicate the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out. The problem was with my data model - I had a circular relationship in there as I was deriving the Period column in one table using my calendar table then linking them back in the relationship!

I created a linking table with the keys in both to make the relationship, then hid it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the fact that `data column` are sorted when data are ingested into PBI. **Calculated columns are calculated only at a later time.**

Therefore:

- you can sort `data column` only with other `data columns` (because **calculated columns have not been calculated yet**)
- you can sort `calculated column` with both `data column` **and** `calculated column`

Solution:
A) `PeriodFiscalYear` becomes a `calculated column`
B) `PeriodOffset` becomes a `data column` (either in your CSV or Power Query)